# Ionic 5 capacitor-community/privacy-screen On BrowserStack- Showing black screen only

Tags: capacitor, ionic5

I am using capacitor-community/privacy-screen to hide sensitive data, but when I use BrowserStack emulator I get a black screen. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack offers real devices that are not simulators or emulators.
Could you confirm with your developer to revisit the code to disable the security flag which they may have enabled in the manifest file or set programmatically in the code.

The class that is mostly being used to set a security flag:
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams)